# \includegraphics within braces with metropolis beamer theme: image doesn't appear

Tags: beamer, includegraphics, beamer-metropolis

I am using the Metropolis theme in beamer, and wondering why having `\includegraphics` within braces `{...}` doesn't work (image doesn't get added in). I get a blank slide (with title) with the code below:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
{\hfill\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}\hfill}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Commenting out the `metropolis` line, (thus, switching to using the default beamer theme), the image appears as expected. So I know this behaviour has something to do with the metropolis theme.

I know I can remove the braces, but you can imagine a scenario where I want some effect localized/grouped, e.g. `\color{blue}`.
I want to know why does this happen?

Comment: If you leave an empty line after `\begin{frame}{test}` the image shows up. I prefer the cleaner syntax `\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}
{\hfill\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}\hfill}
\end{frame}`, with which the problem is absent.

Comment: @marmot does this mean `\begin{frame}` takes a second argument? do you know what this second argument means/refers to?

Comment: Right, but the default beamer theme doesn't have this issue, so I'm wondering what's the difference introduced by metropolis here.

Comment: I agree that one may suspect this but I do not know for sure whether this is the case, simply since I always use `\frametitle` because of problems I had with the other syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem with `beamer-metropolis`, it's a problem with your code.

`beamer`defines this syntax `\begin{frame}{frame title}{frame subtitle}` where title and subtitle are optionals. Therefore your figure is considered as a subtitle, but metropolis has no subtitle commands, then it's ignored.

Compare this

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
{\hfill\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}\hfill}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

with this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}

{\hfill\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}\hfill}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, even without `metropolis` your syntax does not produce the expected result.

If you don't want to leave an empty line between title and contents, use this alternative syntax (or at least don't start new line with '{')

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}
%{\hfill\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}\hfill}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i would mentioned that for titles and subtitles is better to use `\frametitle{...}` and `\framesubtitle{...}` (as recommended in `beamer` documentation). using them the op error will not happen.